# node-gyp c++ chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, node-gyp, gyp, node-api

i need to create chrome extension that can call c++ from js so i use [nodeapi](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html)
and to achieve that I used the **node-gyp**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.13.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "files": [
    "index.js"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node index.js",
    "build": "node-gyp rebuild",
    "clean": "node-gyp clean",
    "install": "prebuild-install --runtime napi || node-gyp rebuild"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bindings": "^1.5.0",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0"
    "node-addon-api": "^3.0.2",
    "prebuild-install": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-spies": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "mocha": "^5.0.4",
    "node-gyp": "^9.1.0",
    "prebuild": "^10.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "gypfile": true
}
```

**binding.gyp**

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
        'target_name': 'hello',
        'sources': [ 'hello.cc' ],
        'defines': [
            '_LARGEFILE_SOURCE',
            '_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
            'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS'
        ],
        'cflags!': ['-ansi', '-fno-exceptions' ],
        'cflags_cc!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
        'cflags': ['-g', '-exceptions'],
        'cflags_cc': ['-g', '-exceptions'],
        'include_dirs': [
          "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
        ],
        'dependencies': [
          "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
        ],
    }, 
  ]
}
```

**hello.cc**

```
#include <napi.h>
Napi::String Method(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();
  return Napi::String::New(env, "Hello Calling From Cpp");
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "hellocc"), Napi::Function::New(env, Method));
  return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(hello, Init)
```

**index.js**

```
 'use strict'
 var addon = require('bindings')('hello');
 function testingfromjs(){
     return addon.hellocc();
 }
exports.testingfromjs= testingfromjs;
```

the problem is it works fine with commands like `node index.js`
but it didn't work when it build as chrome extension
i imported it as dependency and use this as required in the main.js of chrome extension but it didn't work

Comment: `node-api` and `node-gyp` are, as the name suggests, specific to Node.js. To use compiled code in browsers, you probably need to look at [WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm).

Comment: i am develope on metamask extension that already use node.js

Comment: I can't find any compiled parts in the MM extension.

Comment: it is already use node-hide which is based on node-gyp 
beside most of it's dependencies are nodejs

Comment: [Which compiled dependencies](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/develop/package.json) are used directly (i.e. not as part of the build process) in the extension?

Comment: i already need my dependency to be part of build process not used directly 
i need to be used as ledger and trezor dependencies

Comment: Trezor support in the extension uses the [WebUSB API](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/), not compiled code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247098/discussion-between-ahmed-shams-and-robertklep).

Comment: ledger use hw-transport-node-hid-noevent
and this is use node-gyp and napi and so on
what i need to do to make our keyring (JS) communicate with our SDK (c++)
this works fine on keyring level but when it build with metamask it crashed

Comment: `hw-transport-node-hid-noevent ` is Node.js specific, it's not going to work in an extension. I'll refer to my first comment again: `node-api` and `node-gyp` are specific to Node.js.

Comment: Are you sure that metamask doesn't use gyp to run c code?

Comment: The metamask _extension_ doesn't use any native (compiled) modules.

Comment: what?! so how it communicate with the hardware wallets SDKs?
like trezor or ledger or laticce

Comment: I already told you in a previous comment.